# How can I find the number of users online in Linux?

Tags: linux

How can I see how many people are logged on to a Linux machine? I know the 'users' command shows all the people logged in but I need a number. Is there a switch for users that I am missing in the man page? I thought of using the `grep -c` command, but there must be something that is the same in each username for this to work. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are looking for the `wc` (word count) command.

Try this:

```
users | wc -w
```

Comment: note that this approach (an who/w solutions) show only users logged in, not necessarily active users (i.e. users that start a process and then logout leaving the running process behind). Just to give a heads up about the difference.

Answer (score 20):

Classically, the command is 'who' rather than 'users', but 'who' gives you more information.  Looking back at the original Unix articles (mid-70s), the example would have been:

```
who | wc -l
```

Using 'wc -l' counts lines of output - it works with <s>both 'users' and</s> 'who'.  Using '-w' only works reliably when there is one word per user (as with 'users' but not with 'who').

You could use 'grep -c' to count the lines.  Since you are only interested in non-blank user names, you could do:

```
who | grep -c .
```

There's always at least one character on each line.

---

As noted in the [comments](https://superuser.com/questions/13043/find-amount-of-users-online-in-linux/13050#comment11593_13050) by [John T](https://superuser.com/users/1931/john-t), the `users` command differs from `who` in a number of respects.  The most important one is that instead of giving one name per line, it spreads the names out several per line — I don't have a machine with enough different users logged in to test what happens when the number of users becomes large.  The other difference is that 'who' reports on terminal connections in use.  With multiple terminal windows open, it will show multiple lines for a single user, whereas 'users' seems to list a logged in user just once.

As a consequence of this difference, the '`grep -c .`' formulation won't work with the 'users' command; '`wc -w`' is necessary.

Comment: small nitpick - the users command does not print 1 line per user, it just prints id's sequentially, so grep -c . would not work in this case. Smart thinking though.

Comment: this also means that wc -l will not work with the users command, as shown here: http://i26.tinypic.com/4pw0vd.png

Comment: @John T: oh - well, given screen shot, you're correct. I tested 'users' on MacOS X - but with just one user logged in.  When I double checked with a second user logged in, I see the 'all on one line' behaviour.

Comment: to simulate more users you can SSH into your own box :)

Comment: Thank you for this valuable information, although I wanted to stick with the "users" command. Also upvoted you, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Open a shell and type:

```
who -q
```

The last line will give you a count.

EDIT:

(sigh) I misunderstood the question.  Here's a somewhat brute-force approach:

To see unique user names:

```
who | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort | uniq
```

To see a count of unique users:

```
who | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

Comment: that counts all logins of the same user in the total.

Comment: check the re-edit, I think you'll find that the new answers address that.

Comment: This still doesn't work, uniq only removes duplicate successive lines, you need to sort the output of who first.

Comment: that's what I get for posting answers at 1am. (sigh)  fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to see the number of sessions, or the number of *actual* users?

```
$ who
andrew   tty1         2009-07-26 15:31 (:0)
andrew   pts/0        2009-07-27 00:11 (:0.0)
andrew   pts/1        2009-07-27 01:58 (:0.0)
```

That's on my laptop, so i'm the only user, but i'm logged on three times.

```
$ who | wc -l
3
$ users | wc -w
3
```

It is fairly easy to filter out these duplicates though to get the number of actual users.

```
$ users | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u 
andrew
$ users | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | wc -l
1
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bash version of *tink*'s great awk post:

```
set $(users)
declare -A user
for u ; do ((user[$u]++)) ; done
for key in "${!user[@]}" ; do echo "$key: ${user[$key]}" ; done | column -t | sort -nk 2
```

Ok, it's a little bit longer, but was worth finding this one ... :).

While testing, do before next attempt:

```
shift $#                # clear positional parameters
unset user              # remove associative array variable
```

Answer (score 2):

number of the users currently logged in:

```
who |cut -c 1-9 |sort -u |wc -l
```

the above buta with their account name:

```
who |cut -c 1-9 |sort -u |tee /dev/tty |wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

```
who | cut --delimiter=' ' -f 1 | sort -u | wc -l
```

Who prints out the list, cut removes everything but the first row, sort -u sort it and removes duplicates and wc -l counts the lines. Works fine for me on ubuntu/bash :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `w` (`/usr/bin/w` on my Red Hat based system) or `uptime`, they show the actual number of logged in users.

w:

```
                              v
 22:40:38 up 3 days, 22 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.02, 0.01, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
manuel   pts/0    pc-manuel        09:35    0.00s  0.07s  0.00s /usr/bin/screen -xRR
```

uptime:

```
                              v
 22:39:18 up 3 days, 21 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.08, 0.02, 0.01
```

Answer (score 1):

And a method that uses only one pipe...

```
users | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){a[$i]++}}END{for(i in a){print i"\t"a[i]}}'
```

:}

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/who-invocation.html

"who" prints information about users who are currently logged on. Synopsis:

**who [option] [file] [am i]**

Answer (score 0):

You could always download the free tool for unix called TOP.  It produces a list of the users and also what they are doing on the system at the time and will continue to update as long as it is running.

It is located at http://www.unixtop.org/

It has many command line switches so you should be able to extract the information you are looking for.

Comment: I've yet to find a linux distro that doesn't include top by default, let alone not have an option to install it from packages.

Answer (score 0):

```
who | cut -d ' ' -f1 | uniq | wc -l
```

Comment: This seems like a minor variation of Kim's answer, and it contains no explanation.  It might be more appropriate as a comment on that answer (which requires a little more rep).  The intention is that each answer provide a solution that is substantively different from what has already been contributed.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small modification to Avery's answer. Type the following command at the terminal. Here -u option is used in sort filter to avoid the use of `uniq` filter.

```
who | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer]. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking for the total number of users logged in and logged off in a proper sequence, the best command to run is

```
cat -n /etc/passwd
```

Comment: No, that's not what that command does. `cat -n` just prints all lines in the file, numbering each one. You'll get a list of users that exist on that system, but you won't get much login info.